# Edit during migration

Tags: support, migration

I recently answered a question of physics.stackexchange.com . After some comments were posted, I decided to improve my answer - but while I was editing the answer, the question & answer were migrated to academia.stackexchange.com (which is really a better place for it... should have flagged it myself). Link to new location: https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/34548/15062

But when I looked at the migrated question, I saw that my edit did not migrate with it. And at this point I can't find my way back to the original question or my edited answer (on which I spent quite a bit of effort).

So my question is - where is my original question; where is my edit; and can it be merged with the answer that is now on academia?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found your edit. It was still saved on Physics. It's located here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/posts/154087/revisions

How did I find this? From the link in your question, I was able to get the answer ID on Academia. So I could go to the revisions page there. There was a link to the location where the answer used to be located; so I could also get the Physics ID. Then I looked whether the revisions page was still complete on Physics, and it was.

Comment: Thank you. I was able to copy/paste the edit to the new location; including the image (I was pleasantly surprised that that worked). May I ask how you found it?

Comment: @Floris Yes, I just included that :)

Comment: Yeah - simultaneity. I will accept this answer as soon as the time for doing so elapses. Thanks a bunch - this deserves to become a well linked solution to what is surely a more common problem (I can't be the first or the last person to run into this...)